# Line segment intersection algorithm using divide and conquer

Tags: algorithm, geometry, intersection, divide-and-conquer

Is there a divide and conquer algorithm to count the number of line intersections on a plane? I know that sweep-line is a solution to this problem but I am looking for a divide and conquer algorithm instead. I was considering altering the closet pair algorithm in some way, but I am coming up empty with solutions. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: To clarify, I am trying to count the number of line intersections. Not intersections with the plane. The lines are on a 2-d plane and I am just trying to count the number of line intersections.

Comment: What do you mean line intersections on a plane? Line is either parallel to plane, on the plane, or intersects at one points with the plane.

Comment: Please explain clearly. Current description is very vague